# Access The Type of the Containing Class of a Static Method in Java

Tags: java, reflection, static-methods

So I am working on a compiler from the ground up, but am stumbling over how to figure out which class a static method was called through. Take a look at the example:

```
public abstract class Token {

public TokenType type;

  public Token() {
        super();
        this.type = TokenType.getInstance(this.getClass());
  }
  public static TokenType type() {
        Class<? extends Token> t = null; //WHAT SHOULD GO HERE
        return TokenType.getInstance(t);
  } 
}
```

If I then have two classes that inherit from Token

```
public class TestToken extends Token {
  public TestToken() {
    super()
  }
}
```

and

```
public class TestToken2 extends Token {
  public TestToken2() {
    super()
  }
}
```

How do I call TestToken.type() and TestToken2.type(), and have the static method know through which it was called? Specifically, I need access to the Class object of each. Is this even possible?

**Note**
I know that I could hard code in the class of each, but that seems like unnecessary work, and like less fun :)

**Answer**
Hello people from the future. As Niels thoroughly explains below, this isn't possible. You'll need to find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't inherit the static method, so you wouldn't actually call TestToken.type() nor TestToken2.type()... Only Token.type() would work. You would have to inject specific type in another way.

With the simplest of demonstration (Having also added a dynamic method in Token.java):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Token().dynamicType();
   new TestToken().dynamicType();

   Token.type();
   TestToken.type();

}}
```

Where each method prints it stacktrace:

```
Hello Dynamic world
java.lang.Exception
    at Token.dynamicType(Token.java:4)
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
Hello Dynamic world
java.lang.Exception
    at Token.dynamicType(Token.java:4)
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
Hello Static world
java.lang.Exception
    at Token.type(Token.java:3)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Hello Static world
java.lang.Exception
    at Token.type(Token.java:3)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Update:

Added the bytecode for the method dispatch:

```
Code:
 0: new #2; //class Token
 3: dup
 4: invokespecial   #3; //Method Token."<init>":()V
 7: invokevirtual   #4; //Method Token.dynamicType:()V
 10:    new #5; //class TestToken
 13:    dup
 14:    invokespecial   #6; //Method TestToken."<init>":()V
 17:    invokevirtual   #7; //Method TestToken.dynamicType:()V
 20:    invokestatic    #8; //Method Token.type:()V
 23:    invokestatic    #9; //Method TestToken.type:()V
 26:    return
```

Comment: So the type() would always be called through Token, even when doing TestToken.type()?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in there to help you.

Comment: Thanks, just did some experimenting with dumping the stack trace, and it looks like the call is indeed to Token, never even touchs TestToken. Thanks! I'll find another way to do what I need.

Comment: Isn't the JLS terminology that subtypes do inherit static methods, and indeed all members ("constructors are not members")?

Comment: Yes, but that is handled in method dispatch. Once inside the method, there is no recollection of the dispatch in the bytecode.. See updated answers, bytecode from main..